# Showing the Variance of an observable in a determinate state is always zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, observables

I am working through Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths, and part 3.2.2 shows that the standard deviation of an obervable, $Q$, is always $0$ but I do not understand the steps taken:
$$
\sigma^2=\left\langle(Q-\langle Q\rangle)^2\right\rangle=\left\langle\Psi \mid(\hat{Q}-q)^2 \Psi\right\rangle=\langle(\hat{Q}-q) \Psi \mid(\hat{Q}-q) \Psi\rangle=0
$$

My question:

Why does the notation then change to that of an inner product in the second step? And what is the significance of:
$$(\hat{Q}-q)^2$$

**In the book, $Q$, is decribed as the observable, and $q$ is the value of the observable *I think

Comment: Use $\hat Q |\psi\rangle= q |\psi\rangle$

Comment: ...btw: conversely, if the variance in a state is zero, then this state is an eigenstate of the observable. (And what you say is not true/ you have a misunderstanding: The standard deviation of an observable in an eigenstate vanishes--but not for any arbitrary state in general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chapter one (eq. 1.11), Griffiths defines the variance as:
$$\sigma^2=\langle(\Delta j)^2\rangle,$$
where $\Delta j$ is the amount of "spread" in the distribution,:
$$\Delta j=j-\langle j\rangle.$$
At this point in the text Griffiths is just talking about the meaning of variance for any statistical distribution, he has not yet brought in quantum mechanical observables, $j$ can be some ordinary observable like a person's age or something like the classical position or momentum of a particle. Even though we must replace classical observable (numbers) with operators in quantum mechanics, the theory is still statistical and the rules of probability and statistics are independent of quantum mechanics and still hold when we transfer to the quantum realm.
So in your case, Griffiths wants to find the variance for a quantum mechanical observable so from the definition of variance we have that:
$$\sigma^2=\langle (\hat Q-\langle \hat Q\rangle)^2\rangle.$$
This just stems from the basic formulations of the concept of variance in probability and statistics. Now we need to know what is meant by $\langle \hat Q\rangle$.

This quantity is known as the *expectation value* of the observable $\hat Q$. The expectation value is the average of the observable over an ensemble of identical quantum systems, it is calculated according to:
$$\langle\hat Q\rangle=\langle\Psi |\hat Q|\Psi\rangle=\int_{\infty}^{+\infty}\Psi^*\hat Q\Psi\; dx.$$
So the inner products come in through the definition of the expectation value of an observable.

So what is the value of $\langle\hat Q\rangle$? Now Griffiths is talking in this section of the book about *determinate* states, which are the *stationary* or *eigenstates* of the observable $\hat Q$. Since the states are eigenstates we know that: $\hat Q\Psi=q\Psi$, where $q$ is the eigenvalue. So we have that
$$\langle\hat Q\rangle=\langle\Psi|\hat Q|\Psi\rangle=q\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle=q.$$
Where we have used the above eigenvalue equation and the normalization condition $\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle=1$.So we can replace $\langle\hat Q\rangle$ with simply $q$ in our variance calculation to which we are now ready to return.

So we must find:
$$\begin{align}
\sigma^2&=
\langle(\hat Q-q)^2\rangle \\
&=\langle\Psi|(\hat Q-q)^2|\Psi\rangle\\
&=\langle\Psi|(\hat Q-q)(\hat Q-q)|\Psi\rangle\\
&=\langle(\hat Q-q)\Psi|(\hat Q-q)\Psi\rangle
\end{align}$$
In the last step we used the fact that the operator $(\hat Q-q)$ is *Hermitian*, i.e. $(\hat Q-q)^{\dagger}=(\hat Q-q)$ and that for any operator and ket: $(\hat O|\alpha\rangle)^{\dagger}=\langle\alpha|\hat O^{\dagger}=\langle\hat O^{\dagger}\alpha|$.

So all we need now is to understand $|(\hat Q-q)\Psi\rangle$:
$$(\hat Q-q)\Psi=\hat Q\Psi-q\Psi=q\Psi-q\Psi=0,$$ where once again the eigenvalue equation $\hat Q\Psi=q\Psi$ was used since $\Psi$ are stationary or determinate states. Thus we have that:
$$\sigma^2=\langle 0|0\rangle=0.$$
This is basically a statement of the fact that determinate states are such that measurements on the system always return the eigenvalue of the corresponding operator.

Comment: Thank you this cleared up my misunderstanding really well, I have just one question, for the 3rd equation you listed, you gave the Qs hats, which means they are operators, what exactly is the difference $\hat{Q}$, and $Q$? It appears to me, that the difference is quite subtle, as earlier in the book position is described as an operator, but then it is denoted by $x$, rather than $\hat{x}$

Comment: @cookiecainsy So far as I can tell Griffiths sometimes drops the hat when talking about an observable (cf. 3.21, pg. 96). As long as there is no confusion you don't need the hats, however, be careful, e.g. $\hat x|x\rangle=x|x\rangle$, in this equation $\hat x$ is an operator and $x$ is an eigenvalue.  So one must be careful as to whether or not one is talking about an operator or eigenvalue.

Comment: @cookiecainsy $\langle Q\rangle=\langle\hat Q\rangle$